# Where are COM method calls executed

Tags: c#, com

Let's say, I am executing an exe written in c#(just my choice of language). It has the following piece of code:

```
var comObj=new ComClass();
comObj.DoSomething();
```

Now, I would like to know in which process is the `DoSomething` method executed. Is it the same process where the current exe is running or a different process responds to the `DoSomething` call?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the COM object that `ComClass` represents, and on how it is registered. It may be a DLL loaded into the client process, a separate process on the same machine, or even a separate process running on a different machine.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee Probably someone feels that your question isn't perfectly ok for SO... In the end it is a "theoretical" question, and many probably don't like it. From the help: *Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them,*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [COM Clients and Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> There are two main types of servers, in-process and out-of-process. In-process servers are implemented in a dynamic linked library (DLL), and out-of-process servers are implemented in an executable file (EXE). Out-of-process servers can reside either on the local computer or on a remote computer.

I do think that the names are quite explicit :-)

Note that even for out-of-process COM servers, there will be some code in-process that will do the marshaling between the COM client and the COM server

Comment: ok, so, does that mean that a dll implementation will always be loaded in the same process, i.e., in case the ComClass is contained within a dll? Also, if the assembly is an exe, is it always be out-of-process or it can be loaded in-process?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee From the same page: *In addition, COM provides a mechanism that allows an in-process server (a DLL) to run in a surrogate EXE process to gain the advantage of being able to run the process on a remote computer. For more information, see DLL Surrogates.* For exe, I think that they are always out-of-process

Answer (score 7):

This is entirely transparent in COM, you cannot find out from your program either.  It is determined by configuration information that is stored in the registry.  The core reason why COM servers need to be registered.  The different scenarios are:

- On the same thread that creates the object.  Used when the server is registered as an in-process server and the thread's apartment is compatible with the threading model of the COM object.  The most common case, particularly so when you create objects on the UI thread of a program.
- On another thread, if necessary created by COM, to give the object a thread-safe home.  This commonly happens when your *new* statement runs on a thread that's in the MTA, the multi-threaded apartment.  Commonly from a worker thread.  The object you create is a *proxy*, its primary job is to serialize the arguments you pass to a method and deserialize them in the *stub* which runs on the other thread.  It ensures that all calls on the object are thread-safe.  Otherwise the same kind of mechanism as used in .NET Remoting.  The underlying layer that takes care of the marshaling is LRPC, an obscure Windows component that was optimized to make inter-thread and inter-process calls as fast as possible.
- Inside a *surrogate* process for an in-process component.  Not very common but surrogates can be very handy to bridge a process bitness problem for example.  Allowing you to use a 32-bit server in a 64-bit process.  Requires both 32-bit and 64-bit proxy/stubs.
- Inside another process that was registered as an out-of-process server.  The canonical example are Microsoft Office programs like Word and Excel, very common in .NET programming.  This is where COM starts to get brittle, unexpected program aborts tend to cause a mess when the server keeps running.  A *very* common question at SO.
- Inside another process on another machine.  Called DCOM or Distributed COM.  An extra configuration step is necessary to ensure the target machine and proper account privileges can be selected.  Pretty notorious for giving humans a splitting headache, it doesn't get used much anymore these days.  DCOM's biggest claim to fame was enabling Java to eat Microsoft's lunch in the middle-ware wars of the late 90s.

If you have no idea which of these scenarios applies in your case then a utility like SysInternals' Process Monitor tends to provide insight.  You'll see your program reading the registry, telling you where to look, and load a DLL or start an EXE.