# When an method is executed on a DCOM server, does it know who called it?

Tags: .net, com, rpc, idl, dcom

If you have a fairly standard DCOM server app implementing some interface like (psuedo):

```
interface IMyInterface : IUnknown
{
 HRESULT LogSomething([in]BSTR UserName,[in]BSTR Text);
}
```

If the server knew what PC the call had come from, it could work out who the user was without having to trust the caller to tell it. But is this something that is made visible to a DCOM callee?

In my scenario, the client and server are on separate physical machines on a network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are COM method calls executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514872/where-are-com-method-calls-executed)

Comment: Definitely not a dupe, I _know_ the DCOM method is called on the remote PC. I can attach debuggers to the client/server processes on separate PCs and confirm this.

Comment: I don't think you have read all the answers including Hans' one. Or please refine your question.

Comment: The technique you are looking for is [Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691341.aspx). See in particular `CoQueryClientBlanket` and `CoImpersonateClient`

Comment: @SimonMourier I think impersonation is what I'm after... and if an answer to a totally different question happens to answer my question, that _still_ doesn't make my question a duplicate.